# Omniauth-Facebook Redirect to signup form - Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, facebook-authentication

I have an existing signup form that handles users that want to sign up with an email, username and password. I want to have the option to also signup using Facebook. I've managed to get the auth part working fine, but when auth is given by the FB app, I want to redirect back to the same sign up form so users can add continue signing up with a username / password (and add other options in the sign up form) - so really signing in with Facebook can be an option - but they can also sign in with the username and password. Is this possible? Im using the omniauth-facebook gem at the moment, but dont't really know how to re-direct to the user#new controller or where to store the data that comes back from facebook.

Here's a [gist with both the user controller and a sessions controller](https://gist.github.com/4581431).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
redirect_to request.referrer
```